# Obscure low-level fatal error in Swift

Tags: swift

I have a Swift implementation of an Ordered Set that I believe is correct (if not very efficient), since NSOrderedSet won't work with non-ObjC structures. However, when using the class *in a multi-threaded app*, I occasionally get a very low level crash which reports nothing on the console but "fatal error", and shows this in the debugger:

```
function signature specialization <preserving fragile attribute, Arg[1] =
[Closure Propagated : reabstraction thunk helper from @callee_owned
(@unowned Swift.UnsafeBufferPointer<Swift.UInt8>) -> () to
@callee_owned (@unowned Swift.UnsafeBufferPointer<Swift.UInt8>) ->
(@out ()), Argument Types : [@callee_owned (@unowned
Swift.UnsafeBufferPointer<Swift.UInt8>) -> ()]> of generic
specialization <preserving fragile attribute, ()> of
Swift.StaticString.withUTF8Buffer <A>
((Swift.UnsafeBufferPointer<Swift.UInt8>) -> A) -> A
```

The code being executed is this:

```
import Foundation

fileprivate struct OrderedSetElementWrapper<T>: Hashable, Equatable where T: Hashable, T: Equatable {
    let value: T
    let index: Int
    var hashValue: Int { return self.value.hashValue }
}
fileprivate func ==<T>(lhs: OrderedSetElementWrapper<T>, rhs: OrderedSetElementWrapper<T>) -> Bool {
    return lhs.value == rhs.value
}
public struct OrderedSet<T> where T: Hashable, T: Equatable {
    private var _set = Set<OrderedSetElementWrapper<T>>()

    init() {}
    init(array: [T]) { array.forEach { self.insert($0) } }

    var array: [T] { 
        // ***** Error intermittently on next line ******
        let sortedArray = self._set.sorted { $0.index < $1.index }
        // **********************************************
        let mapped = sortedArray.map { $0.value }
        return mapped
        //return self._set.sorted(by: { $0.index < $1.index }).map({ $0.value }) 
    }
    var set: Set<T> { return Set(self._set.map { $0.value } ) }
    var count: Int { return self._set.count }

    func contains(item: T) -> Bool { return self.set.contains(item) }
    mutating func insert(_ item: T) {
        self._set.insert(OrderedSetElementWrapper(value: item, index: self._set.count))
    }
    mutating func remove(_ item: T) {
        var newSet = Set<OrderedSetElementWrapper<T>>()
        for element in self._set {
            if element.value != item {
                newSet.insert(OrderedSetElementWrapper(value: element.value, index: newSet.count))
            }
        }
        self._set = newSet
    }
}
```

The class works perfectly the vast majority of the time, I'm reasonably sure of the logic, and I simply don't understand the error message! Can anyone explain the error message?

The error is triggered by a call to the `.array` property. The calling class is

```
public class XXXItemGroupBase: XXXItemBase {
    // ***************************************
    // MARK: New properties
    // ***************************************
    private var _theItems = OrderedSet<XXXItemBase>()
    // _theItems is used as a private backing store.
    // Do NOT access it directly outside of the class -
    // use self.components instead...

    // ***************************************
    // MARK: Overridden properties
    // ***************************************
    override public var components: [XXXItemBase] { // The public face of self._theItems
        get { return self._theItems.array } // **** CRASH HERE ****
        set { self._theItems = OrderedSet(array: newValue) }
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide code that (eventually) causes the error? – Note that the error message is not displayed correctly.

Comment: @MartinR - have updated question with calling context, and entire debugger text.

Comment: @MartinR - console only shows 
"fatal error: 
2016-10-03 20:27:11.423135 XXX iPad[1513:905399] fatal error:
(lldb)"

Comment: It would help to separate out the statements to see what specifically is crashing.

Comment: oh, and map{$0} in  self._set.map({ $0 }) is unnecessary. You can either just call sorted() directly, or if you want to make it an array just do Array(_set)

Comment: Indeed so @peejweej - first off I'm just asking if anyone has seen the error before before starting to debug...

Comment: @PEEJWEEJ - breaking up the line shows the error occurring in the sort. Updated the code in the question.

Comment: Do you get a similar error using a different concrete type for `T`; e.g., `OrderedSet<String>` or `OrderedSet<Int>`? Similarly, if you instantiate and operate on the OrderedSet directly, rather than via your `XXXItemGroupBase` class, does it still crash?

Comment: @Palpatim - I can't seem to force an error using `String`s, `Int`s or even small classes. The class I'm actually using is quite complex in the sense that it has lots of properties (none of them optional), including a collection of instances of another class (again, none of the properties containing optionals). But neither the sort nor the set membership should care much about that as that class's hash and == are based on a serialisation string that works perfectly well. The only difference I can see is that the app (as opposed to the test harness) works on background threads.

Comment: I assume from your statement that the crash occurs in app, as opposed to in the test harness? If so, are you sure the access is thread safe? The `sort` method is nonescaping, but `_set` itself doesn't look like it's guaranteed to be thread safe if accessed and mutated from different threads. In that case, you might have the case where a sort block is invoked with a reference that goes away or changes because of a concurrent mutation.

Comment: Bingo! That seems to be it. I haven't fixed it (I suspect that means me spending several hours boning up on mutexes) - but taking your hypothesis and sorting etc. on a copy of _set rather than _set itself pushes the problem out to much larger sets, which would conform to the hypothesis... Thanks - do you want to put it up as an answer?